# How to append the same options to multiple select drop down boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to add the same options to each drop down box listed but the options are only being added to the first drop down.

```
function loadIgorMap() {
    $.getJSON('./iGorMap.json', function (data) {
        theData = data;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('.tableBody').append(`<tr>
                <td>${data[i].FiduciaryOutsourcingField}</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="browser-default custom-select" id="dropdown">
                        <option value="NA" class="N/A" hidden> -- Select --</option>
                    </select>
                </td>`)

        }
    })
}

window.onload = function () {


            for (let j = 0; j < theData.length; j++) {

                console.log('I am here')
                console.log(theData)

                let option;
                for (let i = 0; i < jsonKeys.length; i++) {
                    option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.text = jsonKeys[i];
                    // console.log(jsonKeys[i])
                    // option.value = jsonKeys[i].abbreviation;
                    dropdown.add(option);




                }
            }
        };
```

This should display the same options for all select boxes on the page.
Here is a link to a live page on repl.it https://repl.it/@MattEubanks/Vanilla-Mapping-Tool. I added a CSV that you should be able to save in an excel file and then load into the system.

Comment: Where is `theData` defined? It appears to be `null` here. What do you see in console?

Comment: @Twisty if you open the repl it has the information for theData. It's an array of objects. There a whole lot more to the code that what I put in here because I thought it would be overload.

Comment: Ok, I see all that yet it's not clear what the objective is. When I run, it creates the table and select elements as expected. No console errors. All the `<options>` contain the same things.

Comment: all the drop downs should contain all the options not just the first drop down.

Comment: I don't see any Options. What list of options should it be reading from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you plan to import a CSV file and read the Header line. You then want to be able to map the Column Headers in your app.

Consider the following code. I populated variables, assuming all the data has been imported from the CSV and JSON already:

```js
$(function() {
  // Field Data read in from CSV
  var fields = ["First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Suffix", "Address 1", "Address 2", "City", "State", "Zip Code", , , , , , , , , , , , ];
  // JSON Data for selections
  var myData = [{
      "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "EIN",
      "YourField": ""
    },
    {
      "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "Location",
      "YourField": ""
    },
    {
      "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "TaxId",
      "YourField": ""
    },
    {
      "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "FirstName",
      "YourField": "First Name"
    },
    {
      "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "MiddleName",
      "YourField": "Middle Name"
    },
    {
      "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "LastName",
      "YourField": "Last Name"
    }
  ];

  function readData(dObj, tObj) {
    $.each(dObj, function(key, row) {
      var newRow = $("<tr>").appendTo(tObj);
      var f1 = $("<td>").html(row.FiduciaryOutsourcingField).appendTo(newRow);
      var f2 = $("<td>").appendTo(newRow);
      var s1 = $("<select>").appendTo(f2);
      $("<option>").html("-- Select --").appendTo(s1);
      $.each(fields, function(i, v) {
        $("<option>", {
          selected: (row.YourField == v ? true : false),
          "data-col-it": i
        }).html((v != undefined ? v : "(Col-" + i + ")")).appendTo(s1);
      });
    });
  }

  readData(myData, $(".tableBody"));
});
```

```css
.tableHeader {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container col-md-">
  <div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Fiduciary Outsourcing Field</th>
          <th scope="col">Your Fields</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="tableBody"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I iterate over each row of JSON data and make the Table Row from it. Since we want fields for each Select, we iterate over our field data each pass, creating new `<option>` elements. We can also set the `selected` property of each if there is a match in the JSON data already.

I included a `data-col-id` in case you need to use that index versus the column name for mapping.

Comment: Dude you are AWESOME!!!!! I have been banging my head against this wall for days. Thank you! Thank You! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Is there a way to make the selected property match if the fields are close but not exact?

Comment: @Matt you would need to make a search function. I would do it with regular expressions. I considered this as I looked at your CSV, like how could you get it to predicatively select 'First Name' if it found a header of 'FirstName'. Maybe check case insensitive first and then look for camel humps or snakes. `first name`, `firstName`, `first-name`, `first_name` etc.

Comment: thanks to you I now have completely implemented my application. Thank you so much!!!